# Unity "Other Assets" eklentileri gereksiz biçimde fazla

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I export my project in Unity, when I look at the export history, **80% of the size is taken up by an area called `Other Assets`.**

The texture, prefab, etc. that I use in the application. The total size of the objects is **17 mb**. But with the "Other Assets" plugin, the size can increase up to **118 mb.**

[image]

Comment: soo what exactly if your _question?_ welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Other assets means the code and binaries thats not written by you, but required to support the Unity engine. In short they are required by default and you cant trim down the size by removing them.

Comment: Other assets size ranges from 0 mb to 5 mb in some developers. Size is very important to me. Where can I see information for Other Assets?

Comment: Try and open the [Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html), click on the [Memory Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerMemory.html) and in the bottom section change to the `Detailed view` and hit `Take Sample` -> gives you an overview what is currently taking memory in the editor. There you might find what bigger assets you have in your project an have in mind that by default Unity DLL is included into a build

Answer (score 0):

Look in your package manager.  You probably have libraries of assets included in your build even if they don't fall into the folder of your used assets, they will be included in the build until you remove them.  You are probably sourcing some of your assets from folders that are much bigger than what your project requires.

Comment: this didn't work for me the size is still the same.